# How can I have the appropriate distance between two theorems?

Tags: spacing

I have the following LaTeX script:

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\flushleft\LARGE\centering}%
{\flushleft\centering\huge\textbf{\textsc{\chaptername~\thechapter}}}{0.2em}{\slshape\bfseries}
\titlelabel{\S~\thesection\quad}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-1\baselineskip}%
{1\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}%
{0\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}%
{0\baselineskip}

{
\theoremstyle{change}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition.}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exam}[defi]{Example.}
\newtheorem{rem}[defi]{Remark.}
}

{
\theoremstyle{change}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\newtheorem{thm}[defi]{Theorem.}
\newtheorem{prop}[defi]{Proposition.}
\newtheorem{lem}[defi]{Lemma.}
\newtheorem{coro}[defi]{Corollary.}
}

{
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\slshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\mbox{$\Box$}}
\newtheorem{proof}{\hspace{1em}Proof.}
}

\author{My name}
\date{\today}

\title{\Huge\textbf{\centerline{Math}}\newline\newline\huge\textit{\rightline{\ }}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{thm}
This is the first theorem.
\end{thm}
This is a paragraph
\begin{thm}
This is the second theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}
This is the third theorem.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

The output of my code is the following:
[image]

My question is: why there isn't the right space between theorem 1.2 and theorem 1.3?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a *compilable* code?

Comment: I'm sorry. I've add some codes. Please give me some advice, thanks very much!

Comment: This is still not compilable? Do you noy have a package touching the value of `\topsep`, per chance?

Comment: Using \vspace{2mm} per chance can fix this problem, but I wonder that can I get the standard space just like the space between two paragraphs by using \par?

Comment: Normally, it is set with `\preskip{some length}` and `\postskip{some length}`. The default is `\topsep`, but I think maybe some other package you didn't show sets the latter to 0, or another package you load conflicts with `ntheorem`.

Comment: Isn't there another question -- why isn't thre a gap between the paragraph and theorem 1.5?  (The other comments, suggesting that there is another, unshown, package that is changing the value of `\topsep` are most likely correct.)

Comment: I have edited the question and show all packages I've used in the script...I cannot figure out which one conflicts with ntheorem...

Comment: What document class are you using?  In order for anyone to help, we should be able to copy and paste your code so that it's possible to experiment,  So you should show your code in a fully compilable (small!) example that, when processed results in the problem you describe.  The   code you show that would be between `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` should be sufficient for that, but it's not in an easily usable form.  (When you have such a small example, it should also be easy to comment out packages one by one until the culprit is identified.)

Comment: I'm sorry...This is the first time I ask a question in StackExchange...Just now I show all my code in a fuly compilable example.Please give a look again...

Answer (score 2):

Try with `\theorempreskip{...}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theorempreskip{\bigskipamount}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\flushleft\LARGE\centering}%
{\flushleft\centering\huge\textbf{\textsc{\chaptername~\thechapter}}}{0.2em}{\slshape\bfseries}
\titlelabel{\S~\thesection\quad}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-1\baselineskip}%
{1\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}%
{0\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}%
{0\baselineskip}

{
\theoremstyle{change}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition.}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exam}[defi]{Example.}
\newtheorem{rem}[defi]{Remark.}
}

{
\theoremstyle{change}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\newtheorem{thm}[defi]{Theorem.}
\newtheorem{prop}[defi]{Proposition.}
\newtheorem{lem}[defi]{Lemma.}
\newtheorem{coro}[defi]{Corollary.}
}

{
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\slshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\mbox{$\Box$}}
\newtheorem{proof}{\hspace{1em}Proof.}
}

\author{My name}
\date{\today}

\title{\Huge\textbf{\centerline{Math}}\newline\newline\huge\textit{\rightline{\ }}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{thm}
This is the first theorem.
\end{thm}
This is a paragraph
\begin{thm}
This is the second theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}
This is the third theorem.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]